# VBA get interior cell color of activecell then insert hexnumber in to the cell

Tags: excel

I have a code inserted in a module that gives me the rgb hex color of
the active cell when i use the macro button in form of a msgbox.

For example. I have a cell that´s yellow and returns a rgb (255, 255, 0) in a msgbox.
When i use this button i want to it to insert the answer in the active cell too.

Is this possible?

The code itself looks like this:

```
Sub GetRGBColor_Fill()
'PURPOSE: Output the RGB color code for the ActiveCell's Fill Color
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim HEXcolor As String
Dim RGBcolor As String

HEXcolor = Right("000000" & Hex(ActiveCell.Interior.Color), 6)

RGBcolor = "RGB (" & CInt("&H" & Right(HEXcolor, 2)) & _
", " & CInt("&H" & Mid(HEXcolor, 3, 2)) & _
", " & CInt("&H" & Left(HEXcolor, 2)) & ")"

MsgBox RGBcolor, vbInformation, "Cell " & ActiveCell.Address(False, False) & ":  Fill Color"



End Sub
```

i Have no clue how to get it to work.
All ive managed to do is to get it to fill "TRUE" or "False".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the end of your code before `End Sub`, add `ActiveCell.Value = RGBcolor`

Comment: Thanks! I made it much harder than needed haha. I tend to overthink.